# Java - openpdf - Break word with hyphen

Tags: java, css, pdf, hyphenation, openpdf

We are using openpdf 1.3.26 template 2.1 to generate PDF from HTML and CSS. I have a div with the following style

```css
.text-block{
         display:block;
         text-align:justify;
         word-wrap: break-word;
         hyphens: auto;
         width:50px
         
        }
```

```html
<span lang="de"  class="text-block" >myyyextraaaaaaaaalong text </span>
```

The hyphens are being added when I try this on my browser, but not the generated PDF.

Comment: The issue is related to the PDF converter you are using. It has nothing to do with Velocity.

Comment: Which PDF processor do you use for the creation?

Comment: @The5thcolumnmouse i am using openpdf:1.3.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like your PDF processor is limited CSS 2.1. and `hyphens` is CSS3 property.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet once. read article [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#:~:text=The%20hyphens%20CSS%20property%20specifies,automatically%20insert%20hyphens%20where%20appropriate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#:%7E:text=The%20hyphens%20CSS%20property%20specifies,automatically%20insert%20hyphens%20where%20appropriate).

```css
.text-block {
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: none;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<span lang="de" class="text-block" >myyyextraaaaaaaaalong text</span>
```